# Perceptron.predict() returns an array with two values

Tags: machine-learning

Why does Perceptron.predict() return an array with 2 values? This is reference to Chapter 2 sample code from Sebastian Raschka's book, "Python Machine Learning."

[image]

Comment: Hi @enzos, You need to provide the code , otherwise it would not be possible for someone to look into the problem.

Comment: Really hard to tell without seeing the code behind those two lines